# Dense set in sequence space $l^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I‘m trying to proof that the set $A:=\{x \in l_c:\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=0\}$, where 
$l_c:=\{x \in l^\infty: x_n=0 \text{ for all but finitely many n } \in \mathbb{N} \}$, is dense in the sequence space $l^2$.

I already proved that $l_c$ is dense in $l^2$ by showing that $(x_1,x_2,...,x_k,0,0,...)$ converges to $x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $l^2$ for $k\rightarrow \infty$. The proof that $A$ is dense should work similarly, but I can‘t find a suitable convergent sequence in $A$. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

Let me do the approximation for $x=(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m, 0, 0, \dots)\in l_c$. Let $c=a_1+\dots + a_m$. We can consider
$$x^{(n)}=(a_1, \dots, a_m, \underbrace{-c/n, \dots, -c/n}_{n\text{-times}}, 0, 0, \dots)$$
Clearly $x^{(n)}\in A$ and we have
$$ \Vert x - x^{(n)}\Vert = \sqrt{n\cdot \left(\frac{c}{n}\right)^2} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Thus, $A$ is dense in $l_c$. As $l_c$ is dense in $l_2$ we get that $A$ is dense in $l_2$.

Comment: This makes it so much easier! Thanks!

Comment: @Xdelta10 you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simpler to just show that all $e_i$ can be approximated with $A$. To do it, check elements like $\langle 0, 0, \ldots, 1, \frac{-1}{n}, \frac{-1}{n}, \ldots, \frac{-1}{n}, 0, 0, \ldots\rangle$ (one $1$ on $i$-th position, and $n$ copies of $\frac{-1}{n}$ after it) - what happens with this sequence when $n \to \infty$?

After you can approximate $e_i$, you can approximate combinations of them, and thus entire $l_2$.